# Use multidimensional array in OptionsResolver

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array

I am using the [OptionsResolver component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) to set my default settings in a class. Since I'm having a large amount of parameters, I've created a multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'db' => [
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root'
    ]
]);
?>
```

Now I want to overrule the username, but not the hostname. If I do

```
$resolver->resolve(['db' => ['username' => 'test']);
```

the `hostname` param is gone.

Can I a multidimensional array with the OptionsResolver component?

Comment: see builtin proposal here:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27291

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is currently not supported.  However I have seen this method being used, even within Symfony itself if I recall.

```
$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver
    ->setRequired(array(
        'db'
    ))
    ->setAllowedTypes(array(
        'db' => 'array'
    ))
;

$dbResolver = new OptionsResolver();
$dbResolver
    ->setDefaults(array(
        'hostname',
        'username'
    ))
    ->setAllowedTypes(array(
        'hostname' => 'string',
        'username' => 'string'
    ))
;

$options = $resolver->resolve($options);
$options['db'] = $dbResolver->resolve($options['db']);
```

Comment: see builtin proposal here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27291